# Docker v19.03 Windows 10 too many levels of symbolic links

Tags: docker

Im running Docker v 19.03.8 Linux containers on Windows 10 v10.0.18363.778.

While starting with `docker run` command some of containers I get error: "**too many levels of symbolic links**"

```
docker: Error response from daemon: error creating overlay mount to /var/lib/docker/overlay2/b3edd816972f06bce417c0dd91c87c5d0227ff20d891c6a8219a4425aaa5c49b-init/merged: too many levels of symbolic links.
```

Tested with .NET core 3.1 runtime and SDK images, Prometheus image. While other images like hello-world, Redis, Clickhouse running well.

Whats wrong? How to fix "too many levels of symbolic links" on Windows 10?

Comment: Hey, I know it's been two years but have you found a solution? I'm in need of this solution as well (windows 10)

Comment: did you fix that problem? if yes, then please write it as an answer.

Comment: docker rmi -f $(docker images -a -q)      this helps me in case of max depth excceeded and may help with too many levels.

Comment: This command will simply delete all images

Comment: I fixed this with `docker system prune`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this by deleting all the images, containers and volumes. After that, Docker GUI, click troubleshoot on the right-top and then click Clean/Purge data.

Maybe it is possible to fix this without deleting everything (e.g. running only Clean/Purge with some of the options enabled).

Anyway, removing everything and downloading the image again, fixed this error.